# Possible to do an OR binding with 'enter' and 'change' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

On my page there are html inputs (type = text) that I'm binding to with jQuery. When the user presses the enter key or leaves the textbox after changing a value, I want to submit it (using ajax).

I created an "enter" event since jQuery doesn't supply one. I actually got it from a post here. It looks like this:

```
$(document.body).delegate(":input","keyup",function(e){
    if(e.which == 13)
       $(this).trigger("enter");
});
```

And my binding is done like so (any class that has 'submit-on-enter-or-on-change'):

```
$('.submit-on-enter-or-on-change').bind("enter change",function(){
    submitValue(this);
)};
```

The problem is when the user presses the 'enter' key and the value has changed, `submitValue(this)` gets called twice!

Is there any way to prevent this? One submit at a time is enough for me :)

Comment: Could it be that your change is already called? Change could be called very often if you are using a form. Ex: press ENTER in a textarea calls `change` and also calls `enter`.

Comment: @Marnix - the problem is change IS getting called, along with enter. I want to prevent the 'enter' trigger if change is called. IE doesn't call the onchange event when the user presses enter.

Comment: Couldn't you bind to the blur event then? When leaving the textbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the fix to my issue was to simply remove the "enter" binding and just use "change".

Apparently, IE doesn't accept the 'enter' key on a change when using it inline with html, but it DOES work when you bind via jQuery.

i.e

```
<input type="text" onchange="submitValue(this)" />
```

doesn't submit on enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
var submitted = false;

$('.submit-on-enter-or-on-change').bind("enter change",function(){

   if (submitted) return;

   submitted = true;
   submitValue(this);
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to [debounce](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) the submitValue call.

Answer (score 0):

The optional third parameter of the `bind()` method is a boolean that (when false) stops the event from bubbling (thus the handler from getting invoked twice). Is that what you need?

More info: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: No that doesn't work. jQuery passes `return false;` instead of function handler in this case